# dsquery to retrieve multiple operating systems?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, dsquery

To get all operating systems in AD, I run dsquery to select all with "server" in their name:

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(objectClass=Computer)(operatingSystem=*Server*))"
```

But...how do I use dsquery to get, for example, all of Windows 2003 Server AND Windows 2008 Server operating systems in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, in case anyone else is wondering:

```
"(&(objectClass=computer)(|(operatingSystem=*2003*)(operatingSystem=*2008*)))"
```